Is it possible to make chrome(ium) use higher resolution for an image from srcset?
I have an img tag with srcset and sizes specified:
  <img
    src="/img-100.jpg"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    sizes="100px"
    srcset="
      /img-100.jpg 100w,
      /img-200.jpg 200w
    "
  >

I assumed, that having window.devicePixelRatio more than 1 is enough for any browser to chose /img-200.jpg as a source for the image.
But unfortunately it's not the case when I try this in Chrome (or Edge).
My DPR is 1.25, and img.currentSrc returns /img-100.jpg, which looks blurry.
In Firefox it works well, and it uses the next source /img-200.jpg - which is correct behaviour, in my opinion.
Chrome selects /img-200.jpg only when DPR is 1.5, so it looks like it does some kind of rounding to the closest value instead of choosing the upper one.
It there any possible solution to fix this in Chrome? (I couldn't find any bug reports in https://issues.chromium.org for that matter, so I think I might miss something obvious)
P.S. JSBin: https://jsbin.com/joxurilaha/2/edit?html
P.P.S. Specifying intermediate source between 1x and 2x (i.e. /img-150.jpg 150w) helps for DPR 1.25 (because Chrome now rounds to 150w) but this will increase html size in my case, and it still doesn't work for, say, DPR 1.125

After posting this one, I found this link https://issues.chromium.org/issues/331925120
So, I guess, it's a Chromium "feature" and there is no way to fix it atm.
